# Localization not working on ipad but working on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, localization

I have 2 storyboards each with 2 StoryboardName.string (English and French) and a separate Localize.string that contains the string for the view controllers.

When I run the app on an iPhone it's picking the localization files correctly, but on the iPad it keeps the declared values in the storyboard without useing the values fron the files.

I have tried to delete and install the app multiple time, also I have tried to set a parameter from the scheme configuration, I checked the id's from the localization file to be in the storyboard (and they are). Nothing work...

I modified the localization files but the iPad it's not picking the changes.
How can I force the iPad to chose/use a localization file?

Comment: did you find answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

see the target is properly set or not on right side window

[image: Open Storyboard]

Comment: they were checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that an " was missing from the storyboard.string files and xcode was not throwing an error. Also I have changed in the scheme at option the application language and the application region.

Helpful tutorial: 
http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/